# "Default range not applicable" error at second sheet / VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

The concept is pretty basic, go create a summary sheet and start filling in data, and it does work on the first sheet (even though it takes an unreasonable amount of time), but then it then it throws the error "default range not applicable" at this line:

```
  If Len(c) <> 0 And InStr(1, c.Value, "C-") Then _
```

I am not sure what could change from one sheet to the next since they have the exact same structure.

```
'Add a worksheet with the name "Summary"
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Summary"
DestSh.Range("A1").Value = "Account"
DestSh.Range("B1").Value = "Exchange"
DestSh.Range("C1").Value = "Quarter"
DestSh.Range("D1").Value = "Year"
Set destRng = DestSh.Range("A2")


'Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
'summary worksheet.
For Each xSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If InStr(1, xSheet.Name, "ACCOUNT") And xSheet.Range("B1") <> "No Summary Available" Then _

        Set copyRng = xSheet.Cells

        For Each c In copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            If Len(c) <> 0 And InStr(1, c.Value, "C-") Then _


                'Copy to destination Range
                c.Copy destRng

                'Set destination
                Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, 0)


            End If

        Next c

    End If

Next xSheet
```

Comment: Remove the `Len(c)`

Comment: @nishitdey I will. I see that it is also superfluous.

Comment: I was running through your code it was getting in Loop. Also help me understand your code please what is the objective. Thanks

Comment: @nishitdey I think I figured out why my code has been so mind numbingly slow. The "Set copyRng = xSheet.Cells" seems to make it very difficult for the For Loop to ever get anywhere. I am currently working on creating better range parameters which will speed up the code dramatically. As for the objective: The code should eventually summarize data from different worksheets. Since the data in these worksheets is very badly organized and contains lots of duplicates I need to try to get the data through a serious of different targeted for loops.

Comment: Cool, you need to `SET` each and every sheet and loop them instead. Thanks